# magento admin, edit products, tabs on left?

Tags: product, magento2.3, adminform

Is there a way to replace the default accordion style when editing products in the admin area with tabs instead. Example here, https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/meta-data.html this image shows the products editable fields in tabbed sections on the left. I find references to locations in the code but I have no idea if there's some sort of config or override I'm supposed to be doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot is from the older style from Magento 2.0. It got changed to current style in Magento 2.1. To change it back you would have to create a module to rewrite the blocks and layout but it would be a lot to change.

Comment: yeah I'm starting to realize that. I went thru the old commit history and started down that path and quickly realized what you said. I'm going to try a hacky javascript replacement that will approximate the same behavior. Thank you!